# Maven Error - Expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am setting up a spring mvc web application + hibernate jpa + maven from scratch using Eclipse Indigo. I am stuck in this error when doing a Maven build.

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error installing artifact's metadata: Error installing metadata: Error updating group repository metadata

expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...<extension>war</... @13:25) 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried googling but can't find a solution that works for me. I even search the whole project for the text `<extension>war</` and mysteriously, there is no text like this in my project. However, in the tomcat `web.xml` there are a lot of `<extension>` tag, but I doubt that it has something to do in this error because I never touched that `web.xml`

Here is my `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.applicationname</groupId>

    <artifactId>Application MVC</artifactId>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Maven Application Webapp</name>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ApplicationName</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

As Funtik has suggested, I did a build with -X. Here is the stacktrace.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error installing artifact's metadata: Error installing metadata: Error updating group repository metadata

expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...<extension>war</... @13:25) 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Error installing artifact's metadata: Error installing metadata: Error updating group repository metadata
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:583)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:499)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:478)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:330)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:291)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:336)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:287)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error installing artifact's metadata: Error installing metadata: Error updating group repository metadata
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.install.InstallMojo.execute(InstallMojo.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:451)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:558)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.installer.ArtifactInstallationException: Error installing artifact's metadata: Error installing metadata: Error updating group repository metadata
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.installer.DefaultArtifactInstaller.install(DefaultArtifactInstaller.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.install.InstallMojo.execute(InstallMojo.java:105)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.RepositoryMetadataInstallationException: Error installing metadata: Error updating group repository metadata
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.DefaultRepositoryMetadataManager.install(DefaultRepositoryMetadataManager.java:463)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.installer.DefaultArtifactInstaller.install(DefaultArtifactInstaller.java:79)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.RepositoryMetadataStoreException: Error updating group repository metadata
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadata.storeInLocalRepository(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.DefaultRepositoryMetadataManager.install(DefaultRepositoryMetadataManager.java:459)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...<extension>war</... @13:25) 
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextTag(MXParser.java:1083)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.parseVersioning(MetadataXpp3Reader.java:513)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.parseMetadata(MetadataXpp3Reader.java:352)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.io.xpp3.MetadataXpp3Reader.read(MetadataXpp3Reader.java:866)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadata.updateRepositoryMetadata(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.repository.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadata.storeInLocalRepository(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:68)
    ... 21 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jun 27 17:36:23 SGT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/16M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Adjustment Tool</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's just an XML error. Post the POM like Funtik says.

Comment: @Funtik already added it. Please look.

Comment: Can you build with `-X` option? and paste the exception if any? Also more console log from build may help.

Comment: and a web.xml please :)

Comment: Done. Can you please look again? It's destroying my day.

Comment: Do you have file named `maven-metadata-local.xml` somewhere ?

Comment: I don't. Hey I after doing some trial and error I got rid of the error. I either remove the "-" in the version tag `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` or change it to `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. Can u explain me why this happened? Also I remember the first time created the project the error does not exist. After some experimenting then the error suddenly occured.

Comment: I had an accidental unwanted character typed, e.g. 'x', in my xml. That was the cause. Easy to reproduce.

Answer (score 13):

I just fixed this by removing my already installed artifact for that version from my local repository.

For me the cause seems to be a downgrade from maven 3 to maven 2. The maven metadata xml in the local repository, installed by maven 3, contained something (extension) that was incompatible with maven 2. Thus, the new install with maven 2 resulted in the error.

Maven could have been more accurate in its message. Like a file path of the file containing the problem, for example :)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is your artifact Id has a space in it.
Try this pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.applicationname</groupId>
    <artifactId>application-mvc</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Maven Application Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ApplicationName</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Actually, in the pom.xml in my project, there is no space in artifactId. But when I used the artifact id that you gave, `application-mvc` in place of ApplicationMVC the error is also gone. I also discovered that making the version as 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT also removes the error. Its soo weird why is maven behaving like that?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you have access to your repository, just delete that m2-folder.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue was due the extra spaces. To fix this error, i removed the  spaces before the tag on the line where the error has occurred. For example my pom.xml has 4 spaces before the tag , i removed the spaces and that fixed the error

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who has similar issues but is still looking for an answer:
In my case it wasn't an extra space but an unacceptable value.
This is what caused my error:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-jar</id>
        <phase>never</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

The specified value "never" is not acceptable. Simply use a valid value instead, such as "none".

Answer (score 1):

Metadata was corrupt, which looked like below:

```
</versioning>
</metadata>
011</lastUpdated>
</versioning>
```

Since I was trying with jenkins centralized build not a local build, I could not delete the old metadata file. Here is the solution which I found:

Re run the build with Maven 3 & made sure that metadata is updated with the valid xml. Then reverted build back to run with Maven 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error when requesting an artifact from a Maven remote in [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) it can be solved by enabling the "Suppress POM Consistency Checks" option:

[image: the Artifactory console with the option to suppress consistency checks highlighted in red]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I faced the same problem. But my solution was a bit different. I had copied the dependency text from a chat window, due to which some different characters may have been used instead of space. I removed all spaces between groupId, artifactID etc and put in tabs. This resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

There was a tiny space after the previous tag, and that caused the same problem.I was facing issue with `</dependencies>`.

Solution : removing the space(yellow marked below) did the magic.

Hereby, I have attached the screenshot to correct the pom.xml[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but with error msg:

> TEXT must be immediately followed by END_TAG and not START_TAG
> (position: START_T AG seen ...\r\n
> ...

It was not because of \r or \n values.
It was causef by having wrong tag orders. e.g:
I had to put:

```
<a>
  <b1>
    <c1>xx/<c1>
  </b1>

  <b2>xx<b2>
</a>
```

But I put:

```
<a>
  <b1>
    <c1>xx/<c1>
    <b2>xx<b2>
  </b1>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved.
I did not comment this tag

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api
```

so I  just needed to use  `<!-- and -->`

```
 <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
```